# how to convert domain name changing to IP URL

Tags: python

How to convert domain name to IP in URL link, many thanks !

Draft Code:

```
import socket

ip_add = socket.gethostbyname("stopatnothing.com")

url = 'http://ip_add+:80/clients/'
```

expected result:

```
http://204.232.151.56:80/clients/
```

Comment: url.replace("ip_add+", ip_add)

Comment: Do a dns query? http://www.dnspython.org/examples.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import socket

ip_add = socket.gethostbyname("stopatnothing.com")

url = 'http://%s:80/clients/' % ip_add
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote whoever. Mind commenting with a reason why next time?